# Replication Error - Pull Subscription

Tags: sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

Is anyone familiar with this error?

[image]

Firstly, I am trying to set up a Pull Subscription Transactional replication where in server is outside of the firewall while the distributor and subscriber (both are on the same instance) is on our company.

I tried to create a test in my local PC wherein there are 2 instances, 1 will act as Publisher and 1 will act as Distributor and Subscriber (pull subscription type).

The first error I encountered was issue in synchronizing and the resolution was to create a login of the subscriber on the publisher then grant connect on the database of the publication.

The thing is, on the production I cannot the add the loging of the subscriber to the publisher since both server has no instance name so the default of the account was both NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER and NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT.

What is the solution/work around on this?

Note: My snapshot folder was in UNC format when set up. Below is the current permission on that folder.

[image]

Thank You.

Comment: Your error is "server is not found", this means you wrote incorrect server name or it's not accepting remote connections. Can you connect to the server using SSMS from this computer?

Comment: You are currently facing a connectivity issue with your tran replication. Make sure you are able to connect to your SQL Servers using SSMS as mentioned earlier or use the replication wizard tool during setup which will test for your connections.